# error: The method 'getImage' isn't defined for the type 'ImagePicker'

Tags: flutter

error: The method 'getImage' isn't defined for the type 'ImagePicker'. (undefined_method at [aplikasi_scan_plat_nomor] lib\main.dart:61)

var pickedFile = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

Answer (score 0):

There are some changes in the package's  latest version. Try using pickImage method instead of getImage

[image: Output]